# R: mapping GPS to polygon

Tags: r, gps, gis, geojson

I'm having trouble mapping long/lat to a polygon.
Here's what I have
Source:

```
         id     pickup_datetime      long      lat
1 id3177021 2016-06-30 04:58:21 -73.99457 40.72478
2 id1179466 2016-06-30 04:56:39 -73.95273 40.74132
3 id1494337 2016-06-30 04:53:56 -74.00406 40.74302
4 id1665932 2016-06-30 04:50:05 -73.99241 40.74881
5 id1070787 2016-06-30 04:49:07 -74.00514 40.72940
6 id2979850 2016-06-30 04:48:54 -73.99190 40.72189
```

And my GeoJSON Polygons from [here](http://data.beta.nyc//dataset/0ff93d2d-90ba-457c-9f7e-39e47bf2ac5f/resource/35dd04fb-81b3-479b-a074-a27a37888ce7/download/d085e2f8d0b54d4590b1e7d1f35594c1pediacitiesnycneighborhoods.geojson).

I would like to add a column to my table containing the neighbourhood out of the GeoJSON.

Anybody have any idea how I can match my coordinates (long/lat) to a polygon?

Thanks
Simon

Comment: Not sure to help,beacause it is not GeoJSON,  but you can look at https://www.andybeger.com/2014/03/29/associating-points-with-polygons-in-r/

Comment: what "trouble" are you having? what have you tried?

Comment: Well right, trouble is probably a bit to gerneralizing :) I am looking for a function that states if long/lat are part of the plygon and in the best case straight in which of the 'neighborhoods'